# Script to get only the last 30 days of updates

Tags: powershell

I created this script with the help of a few others.

```
foreach ($server in $servers)
{
  if (Test-Connection $server.Trim() -Count 1 -Quiet) 
  {
     Get-Hotfix -ComputerName $server.trim() |
     select CSNAME, Installedby, installedon, hotfixid |
     where {$_.InstalledOn -lt(get-date).adddays(30)} |
     Sort InstalledOn -Descending |
     Select -First 5 |
     Export-CSV $filename -NoClobber -NoTypeInformation -Append
  }
}
```

Its set to go out and look at an OU and then pull all the servers in from that OU and store it in `$servers`. It will then query each one to and pull the last 30 days of updates. It will then send me an email with the report. I've decided I want it to only send me the servers that HAVENT been patched in the last 30days.

Comment: Please rework your question and its title. "Only the last 30 days." can mean everything. Please also format your code and add missing parts.

Comment: OK. So, what's your question?

Comment: How do I get it to email me only if it hasnt been patched the last 30 days?

Comment: for sending email you can use `send-mailmessage` and for getting the patches which have not been patched in last 30 days just change the -lt to -ge. That should give you all the patches which have been patched in greater than equals to more than last 30 days

Comment: The sending an email piece I have its the logic to only get a list of servers not patched in the last 30 daya

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to get a list of PCs not patched in the last 30 days:

```
$notPatchedInLast30Days = (Get-HotFix | ? { $_.InstalledOn -gt (get-date).AddDays(-30) } | Select Source)

# Email if the list is not empty
if ($notPatchedInLast30Days) {
    # Write code so send the list
}
```